# Unable to commit files to Git Bash on macOS High Sierra 10.13.3

Tags: git, git-bash, macos-high-sierra

I've configured my core editor, and everything works just fine. I can open any file in my editor, from the command line.

But, when I get to 'git commit' I'm getting this error:

```
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... fatal: cannot run --
unset-all: No such file or directory
error: unable to start editor '--unset-all'
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

I've tried with Sublime first, than Brackets and Atom. I've even tried to reset the .gitconfig (`rm ~/.gitconfig`) and nothing changed.

It's there any command to fix this error? Or do I have to uninstall git?

Comment: What was the command you initially used to configure your editor? There are several levels of `.gitconfig`, there seems to be a wrong path specified in one.

Comment: "I've configured my core editor" ... by doing what?  Being able to open editors at the bash prompt is a totally separate issue from having configured git to run the correct command when it needs to spawn an editor.  From the error messages, it appears you have configured git to run `--unset-all` as the editor command, which is surely not a correct configuration.

Comment: @kowsky, @MarkAdelsberger, the command was `$ git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"`. But it didn’t work, so I removed it with `$ git config --global --unset-all core.editor`. And after I added the path to Brackets with `$ /usr/local/bin/Brackets`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @MarkAdelsberger noticed, you seem to have set your editor to `--unset-all`. Maybe you confused the order of arguments and called `git config --global core.editor --unset-all`? That would lead to the situation you describe.

Git has three levels of settings: global, system and local (repository). Deleting `~/.gitconfig` will only get rid of the global settings, so maybe you screwed somewhere and changed the editor configuration on another level.
You can try to reset the editor settings on all levels with with the correct syntax:

```
git config --global --unset-all core.editor
git config --system --unset-all core.editor
git config --unset-all core.editor
```

This should reset to the default editor.

Answer (score 1):

It could also be that you forgot to add a message after your commit. For example:
git commit -m "This is my message"

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, was trying to use an alias as the path. Found using the full path to sublime cleared the problem.